# Bouncy Castle Issue when Unit Testing Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, bouncycastle

We are using BouncyCastle library in our android application. It is injected in `Application` singleton in static form:

```
static {
        java.security.Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
}
```

But when I run local unit tests, the system throws me `NoSuchProvider` Exceptions at every place it was using Bouncy Castle.
So, the question is how to inject Bouncy Castle Providers into android local unit tests?

Comment: Is there anything that you did to solve this problem as of now?